# Does z3 distinguish variables by their names?

Tags: z3

Suppose we have the following code:

```
context c;
solver s(c);
expr x=c.bool_const("a");
expr y=c.bool_const("a");
expr z=c.bool_const("b");
s.add(x&&!y);
std::cout<<s.check();
s.reset();
s.add(x&&!z);
std::cout<<s.check();
```

The executing result of above code is 'unsat  sat';
The result shows that z3 regards x and y as the same variable.
Does z3 distinguish variables by their names?
And if I use the same variable in different places, can I write the code as following:

```
context c;
solver(s);

function test1(){
   s.add(c.bool_const("a"));
}
function test2(){
   s.add(!c.bool_const("a"));
}
```

Dose the function 'test1' and 'test2" manipulate the same variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to confuse the *programming variables* `x` and `y` that exist in the host language C++ with *logical variables* `a` and `b` that Z3 reasons about. `x` and `y` both represent the logical variable `a`, and by adding `x && !y` to the constraints you give Z3 the fact `a && !a`, which makes your constraints unsatisfiable.